# Cannot install CMake for Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, cmake, installation

I do not have cmake in terminal, so I went to it's webpage [download page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html), downloaded the "Mac OSX 64/32-bit Universal (for Intel, Snow Leopard/10.6 or later)" item, and the installer does nothing! I tried all 3 of them!!!

can anyone help me install cmake ????? huge thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
system info:
OSX 10.8.4 Build 12E55
processor 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5

Comment: What installer? The tars and I suspect the dmg give an .app wrapper to the files which you access in the .app

Comment: the one in dmg did nothing, double click on the package, nothing happens!

Comment: It won't it is just a directory - the binaries are inside

Comment: Off topic? CMake is off-topic because it's not directly related to tooling?

Comment: After mounting `cmake-*.dmg`, you need to copy `CMake.app` to the `/Applications` folder.  After that, you can invoke `cmake` from the Terminal at its installed path: `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake`.  You might want to add that location to your `PATH` so you don't have to enter the full location every time; or create a symbolic link to it from an existing folder in your `PATH`, for example: `ln -s /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can install cmake via Homebrew.

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install cmake via Homebrew

```
brew install cmake
```

Comment: saved me .... thanks